# Bazel in docker using qemu - Error: couldn't connect to server after 120 seconds

Tags: docker, bazel, qemu

I’m trying to build a bazel project from mac M1 with a docker container with the flag `--platform=linux/amd64` (so using emulation). I’m using the official ubuntu images.

Trying to run a bazel command, Bazel is not able to connect to the local bazel server with a non-root user: `Error: couldn't connect to server after 120 seconds.`. It manages to connect when the user is root (`USER root` in Dockerfile). Also it works with `--batch` flag.

When not using emulation it manages to connect to the local server as a non-root user.
Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be security config issue, not on Bazel side.

It looks like Pulse Secure is preventing bazel front-end to talk to bazel server.
It should work with the --batch option (e.g. bazel --batch info).

Also, you can find alternate solution on [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3602).